# Parse relation string

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, nsstring

I'm developing an iOS app to parse data 
I have a class called @"name" this class contains a string column [name] 
and a class called @"email" this class contains a string column[email]
the class are already related and no have problem with that

In a different ViewController have two TextField and one button, on a TextField the user enters a valid name string (name)

The button display should show in the second TextField the email associated with the name entered. I want to associate this data.

```
//relation class
PFObject *data = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"nameContactMe"];

data[@"name"] = _name.text;

PFObject *DataRequest = [PFObjec objectWithClassName:@"mailContactMe"];

DataRequest[@"email"] = _email.text;

DataRequest[@"relation"] = data;

[DataRequest saveInBackground];
```

here the disaster

```
 //get relation 

- (IBAction)GetDate:(id)sender {

PFRelation *relation = [user relationForKey:@"relation"];

[user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

    if (succeeded) {

        // The post has been added to the user's likes relation.

    } else {

        // There was a problem, check error.description

    }

}];

PFObject *data = _Visitor.text = @"relation";

[data fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *post, NSError *error) {

    emailField.text = data[@"email"];



    // do something with your title variable

}];





}
```

Comment: so you want to get the email associated with the name right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use PFQuery for fetching the desired email :

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"name" equalTo:name];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

   NSString  *email = [object valueForKey:@"email"];
}
```

If you want to fetch the email of current user(Logged in user) then you can use this :

```
NSString  *email =[[PFUser CurrentUser] [@"email"];
```

Comment: correct I want to get the email associated with the name. The class and the association is already done in Parse but no on my textFiedl. for example on my textFiedl name for defect is a name  and the button get email associated on my second textFiedl

Comment: not yet.   look so easy,  I have a class where  name is related to email this works well in parse. Now in one of my textfield I write a valid name when you press the button I want to get the email associated with that name.

Comment: Yes I will try to change something

Comment: continued with the same problem

Comment: Done     [query whereKey:@"name"equalTo:self.Visitor.text];